# Check if connected to GCP CloudSQL Postgres instance from App Deployed on kubernetes engine

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I created a private CloudSQL instance for a postgres db.
I followed the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine and applied the yaml changes and restarted the deployment.
Added the below to my existing Yaml for deployment.
I was wondering if there is any way to test/check if the connection to the DB was successful.
EDIT - I didnt encounter any errors when the pod restarted, so thats the main reason I am asking this question.

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: <YOUR-APPLICATION-NAME>
        # ... other container configuration
        env:
        - name: DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: <YOUR-DB-SECRET>
              key: username
        - name: DB_PASS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: <YOUR-DB-SECRET>
              key: password
        - name: DB_NAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: <YOUR-DB-SECRET>
              key: database
        - name: DB_HOST
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: <YOUR-PRIVATE-IP-SECRET>
              key: db_host
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just to check the connection

you can run one ubuntu or busybox container to check the connection with the Postgres database.

```
kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh

$> # ls
```

Once you are in the container you can run the command from the container to Postgres database connection or run any network commands to check further.

Command to check the **Postgres sql**

```
psql -h <REMOTE HOST> -p <REMOTE PORT> -U <DB_USER> <DB_NAME>
```

Comment: I have already deployed a container Application with the current config for the db instance tho.

Answer (score 1):

[The Cloud SQL Auth proxy container also supports health checks](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy/tree/main/examples/k8s-health-check#cloud-sql-proxy-health-checks), which can be used to check the status of the container.

The `/readiness` endpoint runs a connection test to your instance, so you can poll it to verify everything is working.